# Remove last two characters of value stored in string veriable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am developing an app in VS2010 c# to fetch a single row data from SQLServer and insert it to MySQL.

I have fetched data and stored in particular string variable. Fetching code is as below.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (1) s_name, s_city, s_address, s_added_date, s_added_by FROM tblAQI ORDER BY s_added_date DESC", SSCon);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            s_name = (dr["s_name"].ToString());
            s_city = (dr["s_city"].ToString());
            s_address = (dr["s_address"].ToString());
            s_added_date = (dr["s_added_date"].ToString());
            s_added_by = (dr["s_added_by"].ToString());
        }
```

All stores value in string format. Problem is in s_added_date this variable contains datetime value i.e. like 11/15/2013 12:01:00 AM unable to insert into MySQL I think because of AM.

My Insertion code is as below.

```
            mcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblaqi(s_name,s_city,s_address,s_added_date,s_added_by) VALUES(@s_name,@s_city,@s_address,s_added_date,s_added_by)";
        mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", s_name);
        mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_city", s_city);
        mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_address", s_address);
        mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_added_by", s_added_by);
        mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_added_date", s_added_date);

        int count = mcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (count != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success..!!");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Need to work");
```

my question is what will be the problem in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does a `datetime` column contains `AM`? Don't store strings but the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Your Query is Invalid : you are missing the `@` Symbol for parameters in `insert into` statement  as below

```
mcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblaqi(s_name,s_city,s_address,s_added_date,s_added_by) VALUES(@s_name,@s_city,@s_address,s_added_date,s_added_by)";
                                                                                                                          ^^^          ^^^
```

It should be This:

```
 mcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblaqi(s_name,s_city,s_address,s_added_date,s_added_by) VALUES(@s_name,@s_city,@s_address,@s_added_date,@s_added_by)";
```

**Solution 2:**

```
s_added_date=s_added_date.Substring(0, s_added_date.Length - 3);//stores only 11/15/2013 12:01:00
```

Comment: You are right but looks like this doesn't the root problem of OP.

Answer (score 1):

You should really store the correct type in the first place, so `datetime` instead of `varchar`.

Otherwise you always have to parse it to `DateTime` with the risk of  invalid formats, localizations issues and bad performance. You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string s_added_date = dr.GetString("s_added_date");
DateTime dtAdded = DateTime.ParseExact(s_added_date , "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
mcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_added_date", dtAdded);
```